# SQL subquery sort

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Could one be so kind to assist me with a following:

I have a query that results in two columns one being straight (**columnA**) from a table while other generated from subquery (**columnB**). If I do a sort (i.e. ORDER BY) on columnB I get much slower response then when doing the same on columnA (50+ times).  Is there a way to speed up the sort on **columnB** in order to come close to speeds achieved when sorting **columnA**?

Note: Engine is Postgres

Update:
Query looks similar to:

```
select columnA, array_to_string(array(select ... from tableB where ...), '%') as columnB
from tableA
where ... 
order by columnA
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

**Update #2**:
Solved it by doing sort in new query and then feeding the results to the main query (using where statement to select only partial number of rows instead of a whole set which gave me performance I needed).  Thanks everybody that replied.

Comment: Some extra info would be useful, like the schema of the table and the engine(sqlite,sqlserver,postgres,mysql) to get further info

Comment: Please post the query. I presume you're working with it in another window, is it that hard to copy and paste it for us? Why do people always forget that?

Comment: Well, it's hard that we can help you without seeing your query (or at least a simplified version of it). You could have a situation where the subquery could be replaced by a `JOIN`

Comment: Thanks for responses! The engine is postgres. The query is fairly large and includes number of joins.  I am looking at more general approaches to speed up the query rather then specific query (I apologize if this is inconvenient).

Comment: Bo, it's not 'inconvenient' it's inappropriate for this site. General query optimization techniques are a discussion, not a question that can be answered. Please post the big ugly query, we can help with that - we can't help you learn query optimization.

Comment: Updated with query information.

Comment: I wouldn't be trying to _format_ the output in SQL at all. That's not what SQL is for. Tell us more about what you are trying to achieve here and what are the actual sorting criteria (since without ORDER BY in the subquery, you are currently just getting the random order).

Comment: If this query is being called by an application in .net, java, coldfusion, etc, it might be faster to sort the results with application code after the query is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query

```
select columnA, array_to_string(array(select ... from tableB where ...), '%') as columnB
from tableA
where ... 
order by columnA
```

operations on columnB can't take advantage of an index. Not only that, the sort will have to deal with columns the width of many concatenated rows.

**Your best bet** is to reconsider why you need this sorted, because the sort order of the expression `array_to_string(...)` is arbitrary. It's arbitrary, because you say you're not sorting within the SELECT statement that's an argument to `array()`.

---

> I am using array_to_string to capture a number of values that I need to process later. Do you see an alternative?

A SELECT statement will capture any number of values.

If you need "to further process" some values in sorted order, you're probably better off returning the results of a SELECT...ORDER BY statement without using any array functions. That way, your application code can process the values in order just by walking the result set. You won't have to parse values out of a "%" delimited string.

Comment: You are correctly pointing my next problem (with array_to_string). However I have to first fix the speed before I decide how to solve the sort order. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You can't possibly fix the speed without reconsidering your use of array_to_string().

Comment: @Bo. The solution to your speed problem is to sort **before** you generate the string (so you can tailor your indexing accordingly), and to do that you need to know what to sort on.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: How would you do that? I am not really sure how would that help.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': Mike I am using array_to_string to capture a number of values that I need to process later. Do you see an alternative?

Comment: @Bo. If fields listed in ORDER BY are covered by an index, than sorting is equivalent to index scan (and rows can be traversed one by one: there is no need to hold all rows _at the same time_). Without that, the DBMS must perform the sort as a separate step on the whole intermediary result-set (so it cannot just go row-by-row), which can be especially problematic when the number of rows is too large to sort completely in RAM. I suspect that's what is going on with your current query.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: That is the problem as you clearly stated. I need an alternative approach in order to get results faster. Hvala unapred.

Comment: @Bo. Well, the alternative approach has already been stated _in general_ by Catcall and myself. For us to be able to be more _specific_, please try answering some of our questions.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the unsorted data into a temp table and then index column b. Then run a simple select with the order by on the now indexed column. No guarantees this will be faster, but it is something to try.

Answer (score 1):

Since your "ColumnB" is a computed value, there is no index which could be used to speed up the sort. ColumnA probably is already sorted, so it's fast. There is nothing you can do to speed up the sorting of these computed values, except to pre-calculate them and put them in a table. This is a big reason why data warehouses typically don't work against the live data, but export daily roll-ups instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a bit of different situation and I have update original post. Sorry for any inconvenience. I am not doing any sorting inside of subquery.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer :).  Maybe someone else has  more advice.